# self.table_name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app from an existing populated database. And I have some generic texts (Table_name)="texts_generic" And I don't really need a controller for that. So I just created a model and used `self.table_name = "texts_generic"` however I'm getting some problems.

**texts_generic.rb**

```
class TextsGeneric < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name "texts_generic"
end
```

**users.index.html**

```
<h1>Listing Users</h1>
<%= TextsGeneric.first %>
```

I get this error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/hoteldigital/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Line#4 = <%= TextsGeneric.fist%>
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: `fist` is a typo in your question, not in your actual code right?

Comment: yes :p sorry about that

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: Do you have a `=` in `self.table_name=...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set table name use `self.table_name=` (with `=`), without assignment you're calling getter method with one argument.

```
class TextsGeneric < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "texts_generic"
end
```

Comment: ah christ... i changed from set_table_name to that and forgot the =